# What is included in base image while using FROM while building a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am learning docker and doing some simple hands-on to understand the things better.

I was referring to the docker hub `https://hub.docker.com/` , and referred to some of the official docker images, for example [httpd docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/)

Now, I saw its Dockefile as to how this is build at [here](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/c14a031c014aa2219aea2e73786f577300756f0b/2.2/Dockerfile) and the some contents are as below:

```
FROM debian:jessie

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
#RUN groupadd -r www-data && useradd -r --create-home -g www-data www-data

ENV HTTPD_PREFIX /usr/local/apache2
ENV PATH $HTTPD_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
```

As is evident that this image is getting build using `debian:jessie`.

My doubt is how do we know what all features `debain:jessie` provide (like does  it have a bash shell, does it have python etc.)? Where can we find the info on "base starting point" (FROM ...) , which features it provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a debian linux docker image! :)

see the debian image on the docker store, https://store.docker.com/images/debian there's a "jessie" tag.  that's what you're getting

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `debian:jessie` docker file and investigate what does it put in the image.

For example, it extracts an archive with all necessary stuff:
https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/de09dd55b6328b37b89a33e76b698f9dbe611fab/jessie/Dockerfile